# onClick to call function from another JS file with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following html code in my render react component:

```
<button id="execute-request-button">Authorize</button>
```

And I am trying to call this function from my external JS file

```
$("#execute-request-button").click(function() {
    console.log("CLICK");

    handleAuthClick(event);
});
```

I am calling the external JS file in my HTML as well. It doesn't print to the console when I click my authorize button. Also I console logged at the very first of the external JS file to see if it's loaded and its not. I know the file path is right since I am not getting any errors.

Any thoughts?

---

**EDIT**
I moved my script tag to the top of my html file .
 
`<script src="../src/YoutubeAPI/upload.js"></script>`
 and I get the following error
 `Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3000/src/YoutubeAPI/upload.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.`

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en"> 
    <head>   
      <script src="../src/YoutubeAPI/upload.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <title>STEMuli</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <noscript>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T"
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      </noscript>
      <div id="root"></div>
    </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Where do you place the external Javascript file?

Comment: Why use JQuery when you can use the `onClick` prop in React? `<button id="execute-request-button" onClick={this.handleClick}>Authorize</button>`

Comment: @Tholle Since the function is in another pure JS file how do I call the external functions then within the `handleClick` function

Comment: E.g. `handleClick = () => { console.log("CLICK");  handleAuthClick(); }`

Comment: @Tholle, excuse my ignorance...After I export the handleAuthClick function and then import it I get errors for the ajax saying `$' is not defined  ` . I imported the ajax at the very first of the HTML file

Comment: @The_Enigma Why are your `script` tags inside a `noscript` tag?

Comment: @hev1 , I actually moved my ajax script outside <noscript> (I got some of this code from Google's boilerplate). I can't figure out why that error is being thrown since that is causing my JS file not to even load in.

Comment: @The_Enigma Read my answer. Your jQuery should not be under your own Javascript file if it is using jQuery.

Comment: @hev1, I had to head to work. I'll have to try it after work. I appreciate the feedback and answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you add event click before your code render html.

You can try:

```
<button id="execute-request-button" onclick="yourEvent()">Authorize</button>
```

and define `yourEvent` is method of your component.

Answer (score 0):

Add your event listener when the document is ready:

```
$(document).ready(()=> {
       $("#execute-request-button").click(function() {
        alert()
      });
})
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/n5u2wwjg/90476/

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing wrong with the code. Remember to place the reference to jQuery **before** your own Javascript file. If you place it after, the methods in your own Javascript file will be undefined as it is calling jQuery.

```js
$("#execute-request-button").click(function() {
    console.log("CLICK");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="execute-request-button">Authorize</button>
```

Comment: I couldn't find anything wrong either but the error I posted in my edited post is the culprit I think. I just can't figure out how to fix it.